# What does "Mm." in this case mean?

Tags: notation

[image]

I don't know what Mm. means. It can't be beats per minute because it's not possible to have 4-6 beats per minute.

Comment: Well, it **is** possible, it's just supremely unlikely.

Comment: Is it possible that this is an excerpt from another exercise? It definitely means "measures" as a previous answer has said, but I'm curious about the background of this exercise.

Comment: Is there another piece of music in the book where these rhythms occur in measures 4,5 and 6? This page is a rhythm workshop on those rhythms using the right hand (notes above the line) and left hand (notes below).

Answer (score 8):

We need context.  Maybe this method has its own system of speed categories.  Maybe it's just 'Measures'.  Maybe it's a misprint.  I can't see any connection with figured bass and chords though.   Pity about the dumb '8ths = triplets' notation when doubtless they want Swing.  If this is percussionist training, they ought to know the difference between swing and triplet shuffle.

(EDIT:After reading the comment below from @JimM)

OK, problem solved.  It's the rhythm of measures 1 & 2 of the music that follows.  Thanks, Jim.

[image]

Comment: Does this shed any more light on it?  [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eATmCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=rhythm+workshop+Mm&source=bl&ots=cGXRU7_NJI&sig=9VM7nP-pdui5lnuspW5gGzhehFk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj647vN-YDWAhXjKMAKHRACBiwQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=rhythm%20workshop%20Mm&f=false)

Comment: As I suspected in my (six-month old!) comment to the OP. Nice work, Laurence and JimM.

Answer (score 5):

At least according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(music), "Mm." can also stand for measure numbers. Presumably, the rhythm workshop wants you to repeat measures 4-6 when you practice.

Comment: mm is definitely the abbreviation for "measures," as m is it for the singular.  (As pp means pages, etc.)

Comment: But what makes it say 'repeat bars 4-6'? And why would you?

Comment: Unless the picture shows Measures 4-5, I assume that the only reason why "Mm. 4-6" is mentioned is because they contain the rhythm that should be "Tap(ped)...3x daily".

Comment: @L3B and _qq. v._ is the plural of _q. v.,_ and the Spanish abbreviation for _Estados Unidos_ is, because it is plural, _EE. UU._